# ASP.NET: post multiple variable from view to controller through ajax jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

i am working on app using asp.net mvc 5. now i have partial view that is for to create new record for scheme. this partial view also displays zones in table from where user can select single or multiple which is suppose to assign to newly created record

in razor Html.BeginForm i have add id and using this id I am calling ajax function to send serialize form back to controller. my problem is i am want to send selected zones list ids that is stored in array back to controller along with submitted form values as so that i can update related record in database. array is declare as global variable in javaScript...

### Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#NewFeeSchemeForm").submit(function (e) {           

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Qualification/CreateNewFeeScheme",
            data: { newSchemeData: $("#NewFeeSchemeForm").serialize(), FeeZoneList: selectedZonesList },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });
});
</script>
```

### Script2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedZonesList = new Array();


function AddFeeZoneToScheme(e)
{

    var entityGrid = $("#FeeZoneGrid_02").data("kendoGrid");

    var selectedZone = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());

    selectedZone = selectedZone.FeeZoneID;

    selectedZonesList.push(selectedZone);

}

</script>
```

### Controller class

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme()
    {

        return PartialView("Partial_FeeScheme",new FeeScheme());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme(FeeScheme newSchemeData, Array selectedZonesList)
    {

        var a1 = selectedZonesList;

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FeeScheme_UOF.CreateFeeScheme(newSchemeData);
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Create New FeeScheme!" + ex);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FeeScheme");
    }
```

### Razor Form (to be submitted)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewFeeScheme", "Qualification", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "NewFeeSchemeForm" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 //rest of code to take user input for all variables ..

  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

### Zone table in kendo grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeZone>()
        .Name("FeeZoneGrid_02")
        .Columns(columns =>
          {
           columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneID);
           columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneDescription);
           columns.Command(
            command =>
               {
                 command.Custom("Add To Fee-Scheme").SendDataKeys(true).Click("AddFeeZoneToScheme").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "AddFeeZoneToScheme_button" });
               }
              );
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllFreeZone", "Qualification"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.FeeZoneID))
           )
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html/BeginForm` and let MVC do the AJAX for you? `Ajax.BeginForm` has plenty of options for passing params.

Comment: i am storing value in global variable of javascript array... can i pass that with Ajax.BeginForm???

Comment: Is that global value set client-side or server-side? If server-side it simply gets included as a routevalue parameter when the page is generated, if client-side let me know where it comes from.

Comment: is client side.... if you my kendo zone table... over there user select multiples zone to assigned newly field filled for new scheme record... so my logic is declare global array in javascript and with each user click in zone, add it to array and at the when user click submit button, jquery ajax function is called and send form data + array list... many thanks

Comment: If you updated the value of a hidden field, instead of using a global variable, that will simply post back on the Ajax form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have issue of send both data together but i have figure out the solution ....

### Get SerializeObject plugin

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
   if (o[this.name]) {
       if (!o[this.name].push) {
           o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
       }
       o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
   } else {
       o[this.name] = this.value || '';
   }
});
return o;
};
```

### script

```
    function submit_createNewFeeScheme()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Qualification/CreateNewFeeScheme",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ZonesList: selectedZonesList, newFeeSchemeData:  $("#NewFeeSchemeForm").serializeObject() }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
```

### Form submission

```
  <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="submit_createNewFeeScheme()" class="btn btn-default" />
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme(int[] ZonesList, FeeScheme newFeeSchemeData)
    {
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme(FeeScheme newSchemeData, Array selectedZonesList)
```

try this

```
public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme(FeeScheme newSchemeData, IEnumerable<DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeZone> selectedZonesList)
```

UPDATE:

You can put the selected zones in your form so that this field will serialize with the others.

Add this to your form:

```
<input id="zones" type="hidden">
```

And then before your ajax call:

```
$("#zones").val(selectedZonesList).join();
```

Comment: i debug code and put check in controller against [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateNewFeeScheme(.... but i am getting null values there ... i change code as you have mention

Comment: if i use only this ;  data: $("#NewFeeSchemeForm").serialize(), in ajax function then it works but i want to send array as well

Comment: OK I see the problem. Can you just put the selected zones in a hidden field in the form before you serialize it?

Comment: sorry i am new to this! how to put as hidden field